# How to use partition in Linq C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following SQL table where I need to select one top exchange for each currency

```
Currency  Exchange Date
USD       NewYork  01/12/20
USD       NewYork  01/11/20
USD       NewYork  01/10/20
USD       Montreal 01/10/20
CAD       Montreal 01/07/20
CAD       Montreal 01/06/20
CAD       Beijing  01/06/20
```

I am using this query that uses partition

```
select distinct currency,
       first_value(exchange) over (partition by currency order by count(*) desc) exchange,
       max(count(*)) over (partition by currency) frequency
from tablename
group by currency, exchange
```

Result

```
Currency Exchange Frequency 
USD      NewYork  3
CAD      Montreal 2
```

I need to to implement this in Linq

Comment: [I downvoted because it appears no attempt was made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: @MindSwipe thanks will update with my code

Comment: Are view allowed?

Comment: @MindSwipe in that case you'd be wrong. It's impossible to use such methods in EF Core, at least not without adding some third-party extensions like [this one](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/row_number-support-in-2-1/), which only implements `ROW_NUMBER()`. One could argue an ORM shouldn't be used for reporting queries in general. ORMs and LINQ aren't meant to be a replacement for SQL

Comment: @DragandDrop I cannot create View in DB

Comment: @CaptainComic there's nothing wrong with your question. It's not doable with LINQ over EF/EF Core though. Besides, this query is a reporting query, it doesn't deal with objects, so using an ORM to generate it indirectly only makes things more difficult. You can still map the query's results to objects though, using, eg `FromSqlRaw`, or mapping to a view that contains this query, or create a function that would allow you to pass parameters to the query and use it again through `FromSqlRaw`

Comment: @CaptainComic on the other hand, if you're going to run and map raw SQL, it would be better to use eg Dapper and avoid the overhead of configuring keyless types

Comment: You can do this with LINQ but probably not in the same style you have there. If your end game is to get the result then it can be done but if your end game is to get eg EF do run exactly this query (without executing raw) I doubt you'll manage.. what's it to be?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is very much possible in LINQ, at least if OP wants to re-create the result, not try and generate the SQL 1:1. Also, I never claimed it to be possible or not. I simply stated that it appears that OP has made no attempt to solve the problem on their own, as there are no attempts or partial solutions visible in their question

Comment: @MindSwipe the whole point is to use the efficient windowing functions. So no, it's definitely not possible. This is a valid question - what kind of effort could someone show for something that simply isn't supported/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following :

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Currency", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Exchange", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"USD", "NewYork", DateTime.Parse("01/12/20")});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"USD", "NewYork", DateTime.Parse("01/11/20")});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"USD", "NewYork", DateTime.Parse("01/10/20")});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"USD", "Montreal", DateTime.Parse("01/10/20")});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"CAD", "Montreal", DateTime.Parse("01/07/20")});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"CAD", "Montreal", DateTime.Parse("01/06/20")});
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "CAD", "Beijing", DateTime.Parse("01/06/20") });

var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Currency"))
    .Select(x =>
        x.GroupBy(y => y.Field<string>("Exchange"))
            .Select(z =>
                new
                {
                    Currency = x.Key,
                    Exchange = z.Key,
                    Frequency = z.Count()
                })
            .OrderByDescending(z => z.Frequency)
            .First()
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: This requires loading everything in memory. In SQL, the multiple groupings would result in one group query executed for each outer row, while the OP's query would work with a single pass

Comment: It is just a sample of the syntax and can be converted to a query of any type object.

Comment: How can I return the whole top element?

Comment: What do you mean by TOP ELEMENT.  If it is the linq query result can be returned as a object from a method.  Or do you want the date included in the results.

Comment: @jdweng date and some other fields

Comment: Just need to modify the select.  The 'z' variable is on row of the datatable.  So you can extract using z.Field<string>("Column Name") or return the entire row z.

Answer (score 1):

Running this query (from jdweng's answer)

```cs
Exchanges.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Currency"))
    .Select(x =>
        x.GroupBy(y => y.Field<string>("Exchange"))
            .Select(z =>
                new
                {
                    Currency = x.Key,
                    Exchange = z.Key,
                    Frequency = z.Count()
                })
            .OrderByDescending(z => z.Frequency)
            .First()
    ).ToList()
```

in LINQPad results in

```
+----------+----------+-----------+
| Currency | Exchange | Frequency |
+----------+----------+-----------+
| USD      | New York |         3 |
| CAD      | Montreal |         2 |
+----------+----------+-----------+
```

And this generated SQL

```sql
SELECT [t4].[test], [t1].[Currency], [t4].[Exchange], [t4].[value] AS [Frequency]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Currency]
    FROM [Exchanges] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[Currency]
    ) AS [t1]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) 1 AS [test], [t3].[Exchange], [t3].[value]
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t2].[Exchange]
        FROM [Exchanges] AS [t2]
        WHERE (([t1].[Currency] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[Currency] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Currency] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[Currency] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Currency] = [t2].[Currency]))
        GROUP BY [t2].[Exchange]
        ) AS [t3]
    ORDER BY [t3].[value] DESC
    ) AS [t4]
ORDER BY [t4].[value] DESC
```

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan for this?

Comment: Linqpad, so this is LINQ-to-SQL, which invalidates this answer for EF, esp. EF core 3 with its minimal GroupBy support.